# linq left join with where clause show all from left table regardless

Tags: c#, linq

Im struggling with some linq

I want everything from the CustomerDiscountGroups table, then join a column from another table. If the where condition shows ther are no CustomerDiscounts i still want it to show all the colums from  CustomerDiscountGroups table, and state 0 for Discount_PC ( a decimal)

heres my attempt

```
from c in CustomerDiscountGroups
join d in CustomerDiscounts on c.ID equals d.Discount_ID into cd
    from cdi in (from f in cd
    where f.AccountNo ==  "test" 
    select f).DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
    c.ID,
    c.DisplayName,
    c.Image,
    c.Added,
    c.Added_by,
    c.Edited,
    c.Edited_by,
    //cdi.Discount_PC
}
```

Comment: What happens if there are more than one matching `CustomerDiscounts` record? Or can there be only 0 or 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DefaultIfEmpty` will make `cdi` `null`, even though it is of the type `CustomerDiscounts`. You have to handle that situation in your `select` clause:

```
select new
{
    c.ID,
    c.DisplayName,
    c.Image,
    c.Added,
    c.Added_by,
    c.Edited,
    c.Edited_by,
    Discount_PC = cdi == null ? 0 : cdi.Discount_PC
}
```

It is a bit awkward to have to write out a ternary operator for it and in fact, in C#6 there will probably be a new short hand operator for this.

Comment: Have they specified what the new short hand syntax would be yet?